Firebase - external API call
Можно ли с помощью firebase внутренних встроеных инструментов создать и настроить сесии с логическими запросами к стороннему API для записи/переноса данных в firebase. Формат данных как json так и SOAP?
И естли да то есть ли документация или ссылки где можно пичитать.
